# increasing standard output buffer size

Tags: c, linux, buffer

I'm running a program which starts a process and then that process writes to stdout which my program uses. Problem is, the output I need is about 42000 bytes. It seems the stdout buffer size is 8192 and I don't want it to flush until it gets to the 42000. Is there a way to set this?

I tried this:

```
setvbuf ( stdout , NULL , _IOFBF , 50000 ); // ie set it to 50000 bytes
```

on the code for the subprocess, but it doesn't seem to work at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Note that `setvbuf()` must be called _before_ the first operation that writes to the buffer; afterwards, the `setvbuf()` call has no effect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: No, afterwards, it has undefined behavior. It could corrupt your file or make the whole program (or computer) blow up.

Answer (score 6):

You need to supply a buffer to `setvbuf()` to work.

```
static char buf[50000]; /* buf must survive until stdout is closed */
setvbuf ( stdout , buf , _IOFBF , sizeof(buf) );
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf):

> `int setvbuf(FILE *stream, char *buf, int mode , size_t size);`
>   ...
>   Except  for unbuffered files, the `buf` argument should point to a buffer at least `size` bytes long; this buffer will be used instead of the  current buffer.  **If the argument `buf` is NULL, only the mode is affected**; a new buffer will be allocated on the next read or write operation.

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char msg[42000];
    char buf[50000];

    setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, sizeof(buf));
    memset(msg, 'a', sizeof(msg));
    msg[sizeof(msg)-1] = '\0';
    puts(msg);
    exit(0);
}
```

On my system, the `strace` output shows a single write of `42000` bytes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The data coming back is still 8192. Perhaps its the standard input of the parent process.

Comment: Do you do any other I/O operation before calling `setvbuf()`?

Comment: yes, i have a standard input, ie: fgets(parameters, 2000, stdin);

Comment: @user1276273: `stdin` is fine, but if you did I/O on `stdout` before trying `setvbuf()` on it, it wouldn't work. See the updated answer, and try the sample program on your system with `strace ./a.out > /dev/null`. Do you see a single `write()` of 42000 bytes?

Comment: Sorry jxh - it's actually something wrong with node.js . I use node.js to start a process. That process is the c program. For whatever reason I assumed the problem was with the stdout buffer. But it isn't. There is some strange behavior in the way node.js is accepting data from it's child process.

Comment: @jxh: Note that if this program returned from `main` instead of calling `exit`, it would have undefined behavior, since the buffer is still in use when the lifetime of the array ends.

Answer (score 2):

As additional information to jxh answer:

```
char buf[50000];
setvbuf ( stdout , buf , _IOFBF , sizeof(buf) );
/*close stdout before the programs finishes or even before buf goes out of scope*/
fclose(stdout);
```

you'll have to close stdout aswell because man setvbuff also mentions:

> You must make sure that the space that buf points to  still  exists  by
>      the  time  stream is closed, which also happens at program termination.

Comment: This really could have been a comment to my answer, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Calling `exit` instead of returning from `main` ensures that the lifetime of `buf` does not end before the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

Check the man page for `ulimit` or is that, like, way too naïve??  Because I'm pretty sure that the OS limits user fifos to 8k.

Hopefully you won't need a new kernel!!